# Type '{children: Element; align: string;}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & OmitCommonProps<DetailedHTMLProps>'

Tags: typescript, chakra-ui

When I add to `Box` a prop `align="center`

`<Box align="center">`

it shows me ann error like:

`Type '{children: Element; align: string;}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & OmitCommonProps<DetailedHTMLProps<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDiveLEMENT>, HTMLDivElement>, keyof ChakraProps> & ChakraProps & {...;}. Property "align odes not exist on type 'InstrinicAttributes & OmitCommonProps'`

```js
  <Text p={2} align="center" color="black" fontWeight={500} fontSize="xl">
        <Box align="center"> // here's the error
          {description === "Odpady segregowane" ? (
            <Text color="#9CAD60">
              {description} <IoTrash size="32px" />
            </Text>
          ) : (
            <Text color="black">
              {" "}
              {description} <IoTrashOutline size="32px" />
            </Text>
          )}
        </Box>
      </Text>
```

Comment: in chakra ui: `alignItems` is `align`. When I changed it to `alignItems` , my icons are not centered btw.  a guy who added comment deleted his comment :D

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not use `align` prop on box

I was recently using `alignItems` prop on box, which was not working as it should either.

A workaround for this would be using `<Flex>` instead off `<Box>`

```
<Flex alignItems="center">
  {description === "Odpady segregowane" ? (
    <Text color="#9CAD60">
      {description} <IoTrash size="32px" />
    </Text>
  ) : (
    <Text color="black">
      {" "}
      {description} <IoTrashOutline size="32px" />
    </Text>
  )}
</Flex>
```

You can also pass it props like `flexDirection:` or `justifyContent:`

As the name suggests `Flex` is more flexible and in many cases better than `box` :)